# What is the actual significance of increasing efficiency of a detector?

Tags: experimental-physics, nuclear-physics, data-analysis, particle-detectors, gamma-rays

Say, I have a gamma detector with a 80% detection efficiency. And I buy a new one, with 85% efficiency, or even 90%. How exactly does it benefit me to be having 10% greater efficiency, other than to simply have a higher gamma count? WHat is the physical significance here?

Comment: Usually, it is about 5 %. And then the count rate of a detector with 10 % detection efficiency is significantly better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with any other experimental efficiency, raising this number means you throw away less data. Nothing less, nothing more.

Given that many experiments are statistics limited by the amount of time or money they have this can be a big win in the precision and confidence of final results. But if your investigation is already systematics or model limited than it doesn't do anything useful for you.

Comment: Further, if this is a hand held detector, then higher efficiency means "less time to get the same quality" which means less radiation exposure for you.